# Is it possible to set the tickboxes selected by default in a DT datatable?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I would like to ask if it is possible to have the tickboxes of all the rows selected by default -instead of deselected- in a DT datatable.

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
dataTableOutput("irisTable")
output$irisTable <- renderDataTable(
    iris %>% rowid_to_column("Row") %>% mutate(Row = ""),
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "Select",
    options = list(
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
        select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:first-child")
        ))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write the custom `JS` Function like so:
Here we pre-select the rows 1,3 and 4 (note that the count starts from 0)

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("irisTable")
)

jsfunc <- "function() {arrIndexes=[1,3,4]; $('#irisTable tbody tr').filter(function(index) {return arrIndexes.indexOf(index) > -1;}).click()}"

server <- function(input, output){

  output$irisTable <- renderDataTable(
    iris %>% rowid_to_column("Row") %>% mutate(Row = ""),
    rownames = FALSE,
    extensions = "Select",
    options = list(
      initComplete = JS(jsfunc),
      columnDefs = list(list(className = "select-checkbox", targets = 0, orderable = FALSE)),
      select = list(style = "multi", selector = "td:first-child")
    ))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I copy and paste exactly your code but it does  not work. What the issue may be?

Comment: @Pork Chop, how would you pre-check all rows?